# ¿Cómo saber el schema LDAP con Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Necesito saber cuál es el esquema que tiene mi LDAP por código para saber los atributos que debe tener la entrada que voy a añadir.

Por ejemplo, para añadir una entrada tendría que usar el siguiente código:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# import needed modules
import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist

# Open a connection
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://localhost:389/')

# Bind/authenticate with a user with apropriate rights to add objects
l.simple_bind_s('cn=root,dc=sbarjatiya,dc=com', 'iiit123')

# The dn of our new entry/object
dn = 'uid=user1,ou=people,dc=sbarjatiya,dc=com' 

# A dict to help build the 'body' of the object
attrs = {}
attrs['objectclass'] = ['top', 'account', 'posixAccount', 'shadowAccount']
attrs['cn'] = 'User One'
attrs['uid'] = 'user1'
attrs['uidNumber'] = '3001'
attrs['gidNumber'] = '3000'
attrs['homeDirectory'] = '/home/user1'
attrs['loginShell'] = '/bin/bash'
attrs['description'] = 'Proud first user'
attrs['gecos'] = 'Via6, N#1010, 6th Avenue'
attrs['userPassword'] = 'iiit123'
attrs['shadowLastChange'] = '0'
attrs['shadowMax'] = '99999'
attrs['shadowWarning'] = '99999'

# Convert our dict to nice syntax for the add-function using modlist-module
ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs)

# Do the actual synchronous add-operation to the ldapserver
l.add_s(dn,ldif)

# Its nice to the server to disconnect and free resources when done
l.unbind_s()
```

Ahora, ¿cómo sé yo cuáles son los atributos que en este código se han llenado a mano en mi LDAP y qué estructura tiene el esquema que se declaró en el archivo del servidor LDAP y además cuáles son los que son obligatorios y cuáles opcionales?.

Esto es con el fin de hacer una aplicación que me vaya pidiendo los datos (atributos) de un usuario, lista o equipo de red y que cuando los inserte no den problema con el esquema que está declarado en el servidor.

*phpLDAPadmin* hace una cosa parecida, solo tiene que pasarle la dirección de su servidor y cuando uno va a agregar un usuario, sabe qué datos son los que tiene que pedir para crear el objeto que se pidió previamente y estos datos están de acuerdo con el esquema que uno declaró en el servidor LDAP.

Comment: Supongo que puede valerte la siguiente referencia: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/python-ldap-applications-part-4-ldap-schema

Comment: Hola cómo estás? pudiste resolver el problema? yo hice algo parecido pero sinceramente no se como puedo ver si se insertó o no?

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?